# Is it possible to write the result of a $WPDB query in file

Tags: file, wordpress

I like to be able to write the query result to a file... now this code write ARRAY... useless !

```
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->show_errors();

//insert in DB
$randomString = '"'.substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, rand()).'"';
$randnum = rand(1,999);
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO test (id,tx) VALUES($randnum,$randomString)");

//read DB
$queryResult = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM test ");
$i=1;
echo "<table>";
foreach($queryResult as $subQuery){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".'['.$i.'] '.$subQuery->id.' '.$subQuery->tx."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
$i++;
}
echo "</table>";

//write file
$filename = 'aaaa.txt';
$handle = fopen($filename, 'a');
$filewrite = fwrite($handle,$queryResult);
echo $filewrite;
```

Comment: I what to cache the request to file, because reading file is faster that query the DB

Comment: if file dont exist or date is more than 1 day old... read DB, else read file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing fwrite to file_put_contents that fix the problem.... so here is the solution

```
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->show_errors();
//$wpdb->print_error();

//insert in DB
$randomString = '"'.substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, rand()).'"';
$randnum = rand(1,999);
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO test (id,tx) VALUES($randnum,$randomString)");

//read DB
$queryResult = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM test ");
$i=1;
echo "<table>";
foreach($queryResult as $subQuery){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".'['.$i.'] '.$subQuery->id.' '.$subQuery->tx."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
$i++;
}
echo "</table>";

//write file
$filename = 'aaaa.txt';
//$handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
$json = json_encode($queryResult);
//$filewrite = fwrite($handle,$queryResult);
//fclose($handle);

file_put_contents ($filename,$json);

//read it back : 
$myarray = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename));
```

Answer (score 0):

If its just for caching then you can opt for W3 total cache plugin, which provides database caching too, in addition to all other types of caching.

Answer (score -1):

Before:

```
ob_start()
```

After "/table"

```
$data = ob_get_contents();
//...
fwrite($handle, $data);
```

Is that you want?

Comment: NO... i what the result array in a file mostly like a cache made manually